# expected expression before 'long'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c11

I'm VERY new to programming, and I'm using a book to help me write some code that will solve ln(1+x) after the user inputs "x". My syntax is exactly the way the book has it in its example but I keep getting an `error: expected expression before 'long'` on line 28. Line 28 is the line that reads `long double y = LOG(1+(x));`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define LOG(X) _Generic((X),\
  long double: log(1+(x))\
)

int main()
{

   double x;

   printf("Please enter a number from -1 to +1: ");
   scanf("%f", &x);

   long double y = LOG(1+(x));

   printf("From C math library: ln(1+x) = %f\n", y);

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the `LOG` macro?

Comment: Are you compiling with C11 support enabled?  With GCC, that would be `-std=c11` or `-std=gnu11` as a command line option?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to answer your questions, all I'm trying to do is to solve ln(1+x) with the x given by the user (from -1 to 1) and print the answer.

Comment: Note that your macro argument is named `X` but the macro operates on `x` these two things are not usually the same.  The only reason it would ever compile at all is because there happens to be a variable named `x` in scope when you invoke the LOG macro.  Fix your macro to operate on `X` instead.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be messing with _Generic macros yet at all.  That's pretty advanced stuff.  Indeed, you don't need macros at all to solve the problem you've been given.

Comment: Thanks, I've taken that out and changed a few things that Weather Vane has suggested and it compiles now. It doesn't do the math, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are new to programming, and trying to make an example work, I would not use macros at this stage but focus on the function and the data type. Start with a `double` which is the typical working type of the library interfaced by `math.h`. My example shows how to calculate the natural ln with the `log()` function.

As others have commented, `scanf()` needs a format specifier of `%lf` for a `double`, however `printf()` only needs the format specifier of `%f` for a `double`. Note that I have tested the return value from `scanf()` function *as well as* the number you input, to check that the input was well behaved.

Lastly, you invite numbers in the range `-1 <= x <= 1` yet `ln(0)` is undefined, hence I have restricted the input range to exclude `-1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double x = 0, y;
    printf("Please enter a number from -1 to +1: ");
    if (1 != scanf("%lf", &x) || x <= -1 || x > 1) {
        printf("I need -1 < number <= +1\n");
        return 1;
    }
    y = log(x + 1);
    printf("From C math library: ln(1+x) = %f\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are some sample outputs:

```
Please enter a number from -1 to +1: -1
I need -1 < number <= +1

Please enter a number from -1 to +1: 0
From C math library: ln(1+x) = 0.000000

Please enter a number from -1 to +1: 1
From C math library: ln(1+x) = 0.693147
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer has helped with my confusion. I am trying to do a homework problem, but using an advanced example in the book. I just have one question, what does the "return 0; or return 1;" mean?

Comment: It means return the integer value 0 or 1 from the function you are currently in.  Because that function happens to be the special `main` function, this actually causes your program to end and the value returned can be seen externally by other programs that run your program.  For `main`, a return value of 0 usually indicates normal completion, while non-zero indicates abnormal completion.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your generic macro is written for `long double` type. You supplied a `double` argument `x`. `long double` and `double` are two different types. You did not define a generic branch for `double`, which means that your macro will not compile for a `double` argument. Either change the type of `x` to `long double` or make your generic macro support `double` arguments.

Also, this is a very strange way to write a `LOG` macro. Why are you explicitly using `1 + (x)` as `log` argument inside the macro? What if tomorrow  you'll want to calculate `LOG(2 + y)`? Your macro will still insist on calculating `log(1 + (x))` instead, which does not make any sense at all. A more sensible thing to do would be to just pass `X` to `log`

```
#define LOG(X) _Generic((X),\
  long double: log(X)\
)
```

Secondly, in order to `scanf` a `double` value you need `%lf` format specifier. `%f` is for `float`. To `printf` a `long double` value you need `%Lf` format.

Comment: I was using '1+x' because this is a homework assignment that explicitly asks to solve ln(1+x). I wasn't thinking about long term and needing to change the variables. I'm really not sure what I'm doing, but the scanf and printf in the double format makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @dontdeimos: Where did you get the idea to use `_Generic` then?

Comment: From an advanced example in my textbook. It confused me and I shouldn't have been using it.